# T4MVC 3.7.4 doesn't work in VS 2013 (in VS 2012 it is working just fine)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, t4mvc

I created a new ASP.NET MVC Web Application project in VS 2013 and installed T4MVC package via nuget. I'm receiving this error below when I am trying to Run Custom Tool for T4MVC.tt in the action menu. Line 792 in T4MVC.tt looks like this:

```
if (method.Type.TypeKind != vsCMTypeRef.vsCMTypeRefCodeType || !(method.Type.CodeType is CodeClass2)) continue;
```

---

```
Error   1   Running transformation: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CSharp.Services.Language.CodeModel.CCodeFunction.get_Type()
   at EnvDTE80.CodeFunction2.get_Type()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating98C322A13A6BCC1DAF8B2CBDB87780CF395EE5EDAD72B82A75D505BDDC8999456241B0D6A9EEE4B4EDBBFC85FFB857E4BED539824B09260C2453F2B9684ABF73.GeneratedTextTransformation.ProcessControllerActionMethods(ControllerInfo controllerInfo, CodeClass2 current) in c:\Users\Sergey\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\T4MVC.tt:line 792
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating98C322A13A6BCC1DAF8B2CBDB87780CF395EE5EDAD72B82A75D505BDDC8999456241B0D6A9EEE4B4EDBBFC85FFB857E4BED539824B09260C2453F2B9684ABF73.GeneratedTextTransformation.ProcessControllerType(CodeClass2 type, AreaInfo area, DateTime controllerLastWriteTime) in c:\Users\Sergey\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\T4MVC.tt:line 693
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating98C322A13A6BCC1DAF8B2CBDB87780CF395EE5EDAD72B82A75D505BDDC8999456241B0D6A9EEE4B4EDBBFC85FFB857E4BED539824B09260C2453F2B9684ABF73.GeneratedTextTransformation.ProcessControllersRecursive(ProjectItem projectItem, AreaInfo area) in c:\Users\Sergey\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\T4MVC.tt:line 625
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating98C322A13A6BCC1DAF8B2CBDB87780CF395EE5EDAD72B82A75D505BDDC8999456241B0D6A9EEE4B4EDBBFC85FFB857E4BED539824B09260C2453F2B9684ABF73.GeneratedTextTransformation.ProcessControllersRecursive(ProjectItem projectItem, AreaInfo area) in c:\Users\Sergey\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\T4MVC.tt:line 610
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating98C322A13A6BCC1DAF8B2CBDB87780CF395EE5EDAD72B82A75D505BDDC8999456241B0D6A9EEE4B4EDBBFC85FFB857E4BED539824B09260C2453F2B9684ABF73.GeneratedTextTransformation.ProcessAreaControllers(ProjectItems areaFolderItems, AreaInfo area) in c:\Users\Sergey\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\T4MVC.tt:line 591
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating98C322A13A6BCC1DAF8B2CBDB87780CF395EE5EDAD72B82A75D505BDDC8999456241B0D6A9EEE4B4EDBBFC85FFB857E4BED539824B09260C2453F2B9684ABF73.GeneratedTextTransformation.ProcessArea(ProjectItems areaFolderItems, String name) in c:\Users\Sergey\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\T4MVC.tt:line 576
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating98C322A13A6BCC1DAF8B2CBDB87780CF395EE5EDAD72B82A75D505BDDC8999456241B0D6A9EEE4B4EDBBFC85FFB857E4BED539824B09260C2453F2B9684ABF73.GeneratedTextTransformation.ProcessAreas(Project project) in c:\Users\Sergey\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\T4MVC.tt:line 541
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating98C322A13A6BCC1DAF8B2CBDB87780CF395EE5EDAD72B82A75D505BDDC8999456241B0D6A9EEE4B4EDBBFC85FFB857E4BED539824B09260C2453F2B9684ABF73.GeneratedTextTransformation.PrepareDataToRender(TextTransformation tt) in c:\Users\Sergey\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\T4MVC.tt:line 522
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating98C322A13A6BCC1DAF8B2CBDB87780CF395EE5EDAD72B82A75D505BDDC8999456241B0D6A9EEE4B4EDBBFC85FFB857E4BED539824B09260C2453F2B9684ABF73.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText() in c:\Users\Sergey\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\T4MVC.tt:line 40   c:\Users\Sergey\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\T4MVC.tt  792 1   WebApplication3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some questions/suggestions to help investigate:

- Is your solution a completely unmodified new MVC5 project, or does it have some of your changes?
- Does this happen consistently, even after restarting VS?
- Do you see the same problem with my [sample solution](https://github.com/davidebbo/T4MVCSampleApp)?

Comment: tested it with sample solution on a different PC and it works as expected in VS2013. for some unknown reasons it didn't work on first try, but when I uninstalled T4MVC and installed it again via NuGet I was able to re-run it without any issues. also it works on a new project too.  

Thank you, David!

Comment: Strange. I think these are some kind of VS glitches where it gets in a bad state and the object model throws when it shouldn't. Anyway, glad you're good to go now!

Comment: We're facing a similar problem. A solution of ours, in TFS is acting the same way, but unintalling/reinstalling doesn't work for us :S

Comment: @AnžeVodovnik: and do you also repro with the sample solution?

Comment: @DavidEbbo no, it only happens on one developer's machine, key piece of data seems to be that the solution needs to be connected to TFS. If we put it offline, it seems to work.

Comment: One more thing, when I debugged, the exception gets thrown in the call to method.Type of the first controller's first method...

Comment: All T4MVC is doing is calling a VS Object Model that's supposed to work :) I wonder if this could be isolated to a trivial t4 template. So this method that it blows up on, is it a valid MVC action? If not, maybe you could get further by catching those exceptions and just ignoring the method. Though maybe on those machines, all methods would fail that way?

Comment: @DavidEbbo I've tried wrapping the call in try/catch but it turns out it generates controller files with no methods in them (sort of expected). The project works on 3 other machines normally. I'm thinking it has to be a corrupted install. Will see if we can clean something, or if we have to reinstall.

Comment: Another thing to look at is the list of installed VS AddIns on that machine. Maybe one of them is causing this. Try disabling them all to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @DavidEbbo: Maybe this information is unnecessary for you. But I can reproduce and I solved with 2 steps: 1.Run VS in safe mode (To check the problem is cause because of add-in). 2. Disable Nunit test adapter. Everything works ok now.

Comment: @vfabre Thanks for sharing, as it might help others!