# T4MVC in ASP.NET MVC4 vs2013

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-2, t4mvc

I have legacy mvc3 project wich was migrated from mvc2. There is T4MVC in use. First of all i would like to mention that guys who migrated to MVC3 left ProjectTypeGuids for MVC2. 
I migrated to mvc4 by following [http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806 guidelines.](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806%20guidelines.)

Now i am unable to open this project in vs2010 because its not supported, right?

After i succesfully migrated to mvc4 there was hundreds of errors in t4mvc generated classes and i could not run .tt custom tool again (error in .tt files method GetMvcVersion). I took newer t4mvc version from nugets.

> Now, when i run T4MVC.tt custom tool my vs2013 express throw error "An
>   unhandled microsoft .net framework exception occurred in
>   VWDExpress.exe [6520]" and allows me to choose possible debuggers.
>   After i choose vs2010 (not express) it runs succesfully.

http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/documentation
is it posible to use it in vs2013? T4MVC Documentation page says not.

Over all i got few errors in Views like:

> ..Views\Shared_PaginatePrevious.cshtml(14): error CS0234: The type or
>   namespace name 'Assets' does not exist in the namespace 'Links' (are
>   you missing an assembly reference?)

```
<img src="@(Links.Assets.Images.p_left_png)" alt="<" title="@(Shared.PreviousPage)" />
```

Do i have to add namespace Links to tt template ?

After commenting out all errors, my project is running succesfully.

Overall regarding on documentation wich says: 
T4MVC runs in both Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and Visual Studio 2010, and supports both ASP.NET MVC 1.0 and 2.0.
http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/documentation

Does T4MVC is still in use today for MVC4+,  and vs2012+?
What should i do with VS2013 bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a .net 4.5 solution in VS2012 which is MVC4. This was upgraded from a .net 4 vs2010 MVC3 and during the upgrade I had to upgrade the version of T4MVC to 3.7.4 to get it to work.

I did have to uninstall T4MVC completely and re-install though through nuget. You will need the latest version however as 3.7.4 wont work with vs2013.

Check your version, do a complete uninstall and reinstall if you havent already done so and have a look  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770492/t4mvc-3-7-4-doesnt-work-in-vs-2013-in-vs-2012-it-is-working-just-fine) for further info from T4MVCs creator.

Comment: T4MVC Version is 3.8.0 However i am not getting error in my code. VS2013 just dies during "Run custom tools" command. Perhaps its because of bug in Vs.

Comment: The doc was out of date. I just updated it to reflect that it works with the latest VS & MVC.